# Can a library have a `public` function using `struct memory`?

Tags: solidity, struct, library

I can't find any up-to-dates (and clear enough for my level of understanding) responses to this question that has also been raised very recently on a hardhat issue, with no response to date (https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/2592)

using the example code therein:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

struct AB {
  uint8 a;
  uint8 b;
}

contract TheContract {
  function add(AB memory ab) public pure returns(uint8) {
    return ab.a + ab.b;
  }
}

library TheLibrary {
  function add(AB memory ab) public pure returns(uint8) {
    return ab.a + ab.b;
  }
}
```

any call to `TheLibrary.add` would revert with "Transaction reverted: library was called directly"

Considering the fact that this may be a hardhat issue, I deployed the lib I am working on on rinkeby: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xcA9f1e2eE0f17b225C87372e17135207b5B2BBBF#readContract

here I have a similar problem (though not 100% sure because etherscan only returns "Error: Returned error: execution reverted"):

[image: etherscan attempts]

#### Similar question

[Can a library function operating on a struct work for non "storage" structs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/can-a-library-function-operating-on-a-struct-work-for-non-storage-structs))

- response from 2016
- updated response uses `internal`

Comment: I believe it's a bug on the solidity side, I explained it on the issue you linked. But maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Solidity libraries are not designed to be called off-chain. Smart contracts call library functions. That's why you are getting this error: `Transaction reverted: library was called directly`

The error can be fixed by making the library a contract.

Comment: That's not true for @ClementWalter example, the function is pure and a direct call should work.